# Error getting part of url separated by blackslash

Tags: php, url, explode

I want to get last part of url separated by blackslash 
Here is my code

```
<?php

$str = "C:\xampp\htdocs\sanimailer\storage\mail-attachments\10819_21098672691424384960_C
opy_of_tristan_data_cleanup_version_FBL_3.2.xlsx";

echo basename($str);  
?>
```

I want output as this

```
10819_21098672691424384960_Copy_of_tristan_data_cleanup_version_FBL_3.2.xlsx
```

But I am getting output as this

[image]

Not sure why I am getting such output .

Comment: you need to convert `"` to `'`:- https://eval.in/829073  . why because of this:- https://eval.in/829077

Comment: that is correct.you can post as answer @Alive to Die

Comment: yes that's working fine, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `"` to `'` and then it will work:-

```
<?php

   $str = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sanimailer\storage\mail-attachments\10819_21098672691424384960_C
opy_of_tristan_data_cleanup_version_FBL_3.2.xlsx';

   echo basename($str);  
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/829073

The problem you are facing because `"\10"` converted to that symbol

check here:- https://eval.in/829077